# firebase queries get data between numbers

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For an appointment i'm creating a vaccine app and it saves ppl SSN so like 199411111111
and i need to get the ppl between certain age group so i can see how many doses they have got
the problem is the last 4 because the are diffrent from person to person. So i need to search on the first 8 numbers but i dont know how.

This is how i find the right age group.

```
 cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -intLow);
 Date low = cal.getTime();
 cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -intHigh);
 Date high = cal.getTime();
 String sdflow = sdf.format(low);
 String sdfhigh = sdf.format(high);
 int test1 = Integer.parseInt(sdflow);
 int test2 =Integer.parseInt(sdfhigh);
```

This is how i tried to search for it with a query

```
Query Qage=ref.orderBy("SSN").startAt(test1).endAt(test2);
```

this doesn't work beacause the numbers that i start at and end is way samaller than the SSN so is there a way to just search for the first 8 numbers and not the last 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort on the high bits of a number, you can do:

```
ref.orderBy("SSN").startAt(12340000).endAt(12349999);
```

Answer (score -1):

You Can do - `ref.orderBy("SSN").startAt(12340000).endAt(12349999);`